# Yup.date() convert date into string without timezone after validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I using Yup with react-hook-form and have the following schema in Yup

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    installation: Yup.string().nullable().required("Required"),
    from_date: Yup.date()
      .max(new Date(), "Cannot use future date")
      .nullable()
      .required("Required"),
    to_date: Yup.date()
      .min(Yup.ref("from_date"), "To Date cannot be before From Date")
      .max(new Date(), "Cannot use future date")
      .nullable()
      .required("Required")
  });
```

When I type the date in the inputs, the validation is working perfectly but the date is being returned in the format `2021-03-31T18:30:00.000Z`, however I want the date to be returned just as `2021-03-31`.

I am sending the data to a Django backend server and that expects just a DateField without the timezone. How should I do this?

Is there any way to convert the date without the timezone. I can get it working if I use `Yup.string()` instead, but then the necessary validation would not work.

**Possible Solution Idea (But need help to understand how to do it)**

Can I write some custom validation in Yup. If that is possible then i could use `Yup.string()` and still perform the necessary validation

1. Use `Yup.string()`
2. Convert to date
3. Perform the necessary validation
4. Reconvert date to string
5. And return string

P.S This question has had many views but no significant comments or answers. Can I change the question formatting to make it more understandable?

Comment: Are you sure it's returning the ISO string? or is it returning a Date object that when logged is represented by its toString() method which returns said ISO string?

Comment: You may want to check out their custom transform -> `date().transform((value, originalValue) => {});`

Comment: @Ishettyl I checked their transform method but if I convert it to the string then validations do not run and it says that it is not correct datatype required by Yup.date()

Comment: @pilchard I am not exactly sure but I cant have the timezone info as the backend API cannot work with that

Comment: nullable() .required("Required") doens't make sense much. If you want to be null value, then remove required and provide true to nullable(true). This is just another point on the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a quick function in order to change the format before to go head with further validation of yup.
In order to do that you can use `date-fns` helper.

```
import parse from "date-fns/parse";

function parseDateString(value, originalValue) {
  return isDate(originalValue)
    ? originalValue  // this make sure that a value is provided
    : parse(originalValue, "yyyy-MM-dd", new Date());
}
```

Than can be used in this way:

```
import { date, object } from "yup";

const today = new Date();

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  installation: Yup.string().nullable().required("Required"),
  from_date: Yup.date()
    .transform(parseDateString)
    .max(new Date(), "Cannot use future date")
    .required("Required"),
  to_date: Yup.date()
    .min(Yup.ref("from_date"), "To Date cannot be before From Date")
    .max(new Date(), "Cannot use future date")
    .required("Required")
});
```

Comment: note that `.transform()` doesn't apply if `strict: true` is set in the schema options ([src](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematransformcurrentvalue-any-originalvalue-any--any-schema))

Comment: @fredrivett in the question is not mentioned at all the strict environment. On top of that .transform is simply a function that can either be subsituted or re-implemented from scratch.

Comment: @CarmineTambascia that's fair, just making a note for other people who got confused why it wasn't working in their setup, not criticising the answer.